# Handling AutoRelease Pools and Threads

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, nsautoreleasepool

If I create a thread with a callback like..

```
NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
while(1) {
   //Process Stuff
}
[pool release];
```

I assume that anything autoreleased will never really be freed since the pool is never drained.
I could change things around to be like this:

```
while(1) {
   NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
   //Process Stuff
   [pool release];
}
```

But it seems a bit wasteful to alloc/delete so often.  Is there a way I can set aside a block of memory and release the pool once its full?

Comment: What does "full" mean? Autorelease pools don't have any particular limit on their capacity.

Comment: I guess thats what I was curious about.  If there was a way to limit the capacity or query the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allocate a significant* amount of autoreleased memory in each iteration of your loop, then creating and releasing a new pool for each iteration is the proper thing to do, to prevent the memory from piling up.

If you don't generate much autoreleased memory, then it wouldn't be beneficial and you will only need the outer pool.

If you allocate enough memory that a single iteration is insignificant, but there is a lot by the time you are done, then you could create and release the pool every X iterations.

```
#define IterationsPerPool 10
NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
int x = 0;
while(1) {
   //Process Stuff
   if(++x == IterationsPerPool) {
      x = 0;
      [pool release];
      pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
   }
}
[pool release];
```

* You need to determine what *significant* is for yourself.

Comment: This is almost assuredly a waste of code;   you'd have to spin the while() loop really fast and do very little in it for the overhead of pool allocation to matter.   Unless you have measured a performance issue, **do not bother with this premature optimization**.

Answer (score 7):

Don't worry about it, because [Autorelease is Fast](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/autorelease-is-fast.html). Your second option is fine. And in fact, in ARC, it will be hard to do anything besides those two options because of the new `@autoreleasepool { }` syntax.

Comment: Exactly.  *But it seems a bit wasteful to alloc/delete so often*.  **Seems slow** is never a good reason to optimize something.